# Roboto font-package messes up ToC

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, koma-script

In my `koma`-document, loading the package `roboto` for using the *Roboto* font as sans-serif messes up the indentation of the ToC.

Do you know **what causes this misbehavior, and how I could fix it?**

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
    %\usepackage{roboto}\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contents with roboto}%% <== uncomment to see the effet of `roboto` package
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \part{Part1}
        \chapter{Chap1}
            \section{Sec1}
            \section{Sec2}
            \section{Sec3}
        \chapter{Chap2}
            \section{Sec1}
            \section{Sec2}
            \section{Sec3}
        \chapter{Chap3}
            \section{Sec1}
            \section{Sec2}
            \section{Sec3}                      
\end{document}
```

Comment: Update your TeX distribution: it was a bug in `mweights.sty` that has already been fixed.

Comment: @egreg my bad, I should have had the reflex to update TeXlive. Thank you for your answer though.

Comment: No problem! This bug has bitten several people, but happily it was easy to fix it.